# Properly document C# event delegates

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I hope I'm using the right terminology.

I want to document a public event Action<> delegate

```
public event Action<int, int, WriteableBitmap, Exception> OperationDone
```

For this I want the user to know which generic stands for what. So I was thinking of something like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Event triggers if a thumbnail image has been loaded. If loading a thumbnail was requested and the request has failed, 
    /// the causing exception will be passed as argument (otherwise null).
    /// pdfViewerPage, newViewerPage, bitmap, exception
    /// <param name="pdfViewerPage"/> viewer page of the thumbnail at the time of the request creation
    /// <param name="newViewerPage"/> viewer page of the thumbnail at the time of the request completion
    /// <param name="bitmap"/> Bitmap of the thumbnail
    /// <param name="exception"/> Exception of the request
    /// </summary>
```

But this gives me warnings since the delegate doesn't define parameters. Is there a way to nicely document this or do I have to stick to just use the `summary`?

Comment: Do consider the standard way events are declared in the .NET Framework, they use `EventHandler<T>`.  Highly recognizable by anybody that uses your library.  And you get to document T very easily.

Comment: Indeed I read about this, and I am considering this. I'm working into existing code and I wanted to stick to their design due to time restraints. But yes, using `EventHandler<T>` is something that I added to my todo list :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [typeparam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173191.aspx)  instead:

```
/// <typeparam name="pdfViewerPage"> viewer page of the thumbnail at the time of the request creation</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="newViewerPage"> viewer page of the thumbnail at the time of the request completion</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="bitmap"> Bitmap of the thumbnail</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="exception"> Exception of the request</typeparam>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even when I use `typeparam` it complains during compilation: `OperationDone has a typeparamref tag for 'int', but there is no type parameter by that name`. Same if I replace `int` with `pdfViewerPage`

Comment: @Philipp try `T1`, `T2`, etc. instead of the type name

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I tried that too, doesn't solve the problem. For now I just expanded the summary with the information but I will try to change the code to use EventHandlers.